# Why SSL option was not applied?

Tags: postgresql

I generated certificate files and have configured my PostgreSQL server to use SSL:

```
postgres=# select * from pg_file_settings where name = 'ssl';
              sourcefile               | sourceline | seqno | name | setting | applied | error
---------------------------------------+------------+-------+------+---------+---------+-------
 /dbdata/postgres/postgresql.conf      |        105 |     3 | ssl  | on      | f       |
 /dbdata/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf |          3 |    23 | ssl  | off     | t       |
(2 rows)
```

In my log files I can see:

```
2024-01-17 16:59:10.843 UTC [6] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.5 (Debian 15.5-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-01-17 16:59:10.843 UTC [6] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-01-17 16:59:10.843 UTC [6] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-01-17 16:59:10.848 UTC [6] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] CONTEXT:  line 102 of configuration file "/dbdata/postgres/pg_hba.conf"
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] CONTEXT:  line 103 of configuration file "/dbdata/postgres/pg_hba.conf"
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2024-01-17 16:59:10.851 UTC [6] CONTEXT:  line 104 of configuration file "/dbdata/postgres/pg_hba.conf"
2024-01-17 16:59:10.855 UTC [36] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-17 16:58:51 UTC
2024-01-17 16:59:10.861 UTC [6] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Why `ssl` was not enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dbdata/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf |          3 |    23 | ssl  | off`

From here [Config Setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html):

> In addition to postgresql.conf, a PostgreSQL data directory contains a file postgresql.auto.conf, which has the same format as postgresql.conf but is intended to be edited automatically, not manually. This file holds settings provided through the ALTER SYSTEM command. This file is read whenever postgresql.conf is, and its settings take effect in the same way. Settings in postgresql.auto.conf override those in postgresql.conf.

For how to reverse see [Alter System](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html).

Would not hurt to open `/dbdata/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf` to see what else may have been set by `ALTER SYSTEM`. **DO NOT** change the settings in the file use `ALTER SYSTEM` for that.